# Stripe's payementintent api gives error when the iframe loads

Tags: iframe, stripe-payments, payment

i am getting this error

Refused to frame 'URL' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'

i have initialized it like this

````
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
    
    let options = {
        clientSecret: "<%= @intent.client_secret%>",
        appearance:{ theme: 'flat'}
    }


    const elements = stripe.elements(options);

    const paymentElement = elements.create('payment');
    paymentElement.mount('#payment-element');
    
    const form = document.getElementById('payment-form');

    form.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        
      const {error} = await stripe.confirmPayment({
        elements,
        confirmParams: {
          return_url: 'return url',
        },
      });
    
      if (error) {
        const messageContainer = document.querySelector('#error-message');
        messageContainer.textContent = error.message;
      } else {
        // Your customer will be redirected to your `return_url`. For some payment
        // methods like iDEAL, your customer will be redirected to an intermediate
        // site first to authorize the payment, then redirected to the `return_url`.
       
      }
    });
    
}
initialize();```

I can enter the card details but when i submit it gives an error
````